# Does Google BigQuery support EWKB (Extended Well-Known binary)?

Tags: google-bigquery

Does Google BigQuery support EWKB (Extended Well-Known binary) ?

If not, is there any workaround recommended?

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery supports GeoJSON, WKT, WKB formats at present. For now, it does not support EWKB.

The workaround for now is covert it to WKT using the [ST_AsText function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_astext)

Comment: Since EWKB is not recognize as a geometry by BigQuery, how could you manipulate EWKB Hex using ST_AsText_function?